# Juju bootstrap and time gets expired

Tags: juju, maas

Why sometimes when I bootstrap, this stays here forever?

[image: the bootstrapped node]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is "stuck" there, can you ssh into 172.16.1.141 (the address from your screenshot, it will vary between attempts) as ubuntu, from the same machine where you are bootstrapping from? I've seen this before and there was a stuck dpkg or apt-get process on that node as a result of an incorrect MTU. Meaning, ssh worked, but as soon as a transfer of something larger than a few keystrokes in a terminal happened, like a package download, it would get stuck.